# Having trouble accessing value from JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have to try to access the value of "text" which is 4.9 in the JSON data below in PHP.

```
$json = '{"destination_addresses" : [ "Ibadan-Abeokuta Rd, Mokola, Ibadan, Nigeria" ],
 "origin_addresses" : [ "Ogunwale Crescent, Ibadan, Nigeria" ], 
 "rows" : [ 
     { "elements" : [
          { "distance" : 
            { "text" : "4.9 mi", "value" : 7819 }, 
            "duration" : { "text" : "18 mins", "value" : 1067 }, 
            "status" : "OK" }
                
                    ]
         } 
        ]
         
         , "status" : "OK" }';
```

Comment: how are you accessing that in php?

Comment: i need to get the value of the data using json_decode

Comment: So what have you tried and what’s the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is a little bit complex. I have a solution below that access `text` property from the nested JSON.

```
$array = json_decode( $json, true ); 
echo ($array['rows'][0] ["elements"][0]['distance']['text']);
```